# Want to use Context instead of Activity for RunOnUIThread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I'm creating an Android app, with an ListAdapter for my RecyclerView. I want to use this in different Activities. But when I try to do this with `((Activity)context)` my app chrashes. Then I tried it with a handler and runnable, but there my layout gets messed up. And to do it with `switch(ActivityName)` isn't a good way, is it?. Is there anything else that I can do? Do you have an answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need context too.

```
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Your code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, but there my layout gets messed up. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

where you are using Recyler view in an Activity or Fragment ,

and try with following code

adapter = new AdapterName(Activity Name / Fagment name , ........... )

hope it will work other wise you need to paste your code

Answer (score 0):

Make static variable of your activity and store the context

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static MainActivity mainActivity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainActivity=this;
    }
}
```

Now you can acess your activity from anywhere like this

```
 MainActivity.mainactivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
    });
```